# PHP Parse XML using SimpleXML can't get string

Tags: php, xml

I have tried a few examples I have found on answers made here, while I can get some parts of the XML using SimpleXML I am unable to get the part I need.

for instance, I can get the parts that are on top, they are not nested or anything, but the ones I need I have tried many ways and I can't.

for example i can get the bw info:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_file("http://163.172.209.150/stats");
$xml1->bw_in;
$xml1->bw_out;
```

but i am having trouble getting this part that says the number of users connected

```
["nclients"]=>
string(3) "146"
```

which is located all the wyay on the bottom, i have also tried using a foreach in other to get each stream users and just addd them up but i can't get that either.

is there some way I can get the number output by the nclients?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, I used XPath to get the result.

```
$xml->xpath("/rtmp/server/application/live/nclients");
```